# How to create a dynamic - calculated - field in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Salesforce:

Every account has an agreement with my company. Once they have an agreement in place, they can start ordering products.

In the account record, I have a **date** field called "Agreement Approved On".

Ordered products are represented as "assets".

I want to create another field in the account record called "First Order Amount". This field should be populated dynamically, and should calculate the following:

1. Look for all of the account's assets created **after** the date field "Agreement Approved On".
2. Summarize the total of all assets ordered during the first order (within the same day).

*Within the same day:*

- Let's assume the agreement was approved on January 1 2017. The
  account started ordering on January 5 2017.
- During January 5 2017, the account made 5 orders (8 different
  assets), total is $1,000. **This is the first order total - within the same
  day**.
- After January 5 2017, the account made more orders, but they don't
  count towards "first order amount".

So my question is - how do I create this "First Order Amount" field?

Thanks!

Comment: Just create that field in Account Object and use whenever you want that in apex and update it...why you have to create that dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a oncreate trigger on Asset taht will update the first order total amount field on Account.
In the trigger check whether now() > agreement approve date. If yes, check if there are any other assets with dateCreated < TODAY.
These two conditions will check whether there are any existing account assets and if the date is > agreement date. If there are existing assets, it means this is not the first order.
You can then get all asset amounts and add them and write the final amount to the account field.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm 
for trigger syntax

and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm for date functions and literals.